# How to reset "Suppress X warning if annotated by Y" in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

In the newer intellij version a useful feature "Suppress X warning if annotated by Y" was added. I mistakenly applied it to "unused" warning, and want to roll that back. But I find no such option in the settings.

Basically I **do** want to get warnings when fields are not used even if annotated by @Inject or whatever.

Comment: Check the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Inspections | Java -> **Unused declaration** -> **Entry points**. You can also reset the inspection settings to defaults by selecting **Restore Default** option for the selected Inspection profile.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey. This is what I was looking for:
Under Entry Points | Annotations...
Also worth mentioning that there's a Project and an IDE profile for these preferences. The change I wanted to rollback was stored under Project profile.

Can you post this as an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: FYI: Groovy seems to inherit the Entry Point Annotations defined by the Java inspection.